# Async/Await NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working with Node.js and am having some trouble with async/await. My project refetches data from several endpoints once a day, and does so by calling one broad refetch function:

```
async function refetch() {
  await refetchOne();
  await refetchTwo();
  await refetchThree();
  await refetchFour();
  await refetchFive();
}
```

Right now, I want to it to refetch in a certain order (as specified above, 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5).  However, sometimes the order is not maintained (i.e. refetchFive gets called and finishes before Four or Three are finished.  How can I make sure that the next refetch function is only called after the previous one finishes?

Comment: If your code and all async calls in it are really like you shown us then you can't get a situation: `refetchFive gets called and finishes before Four or Three are finished`. Show some piece of real code so that we make sure you describe your issue correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to run an array of async/await functions in series is to use for...of. This will execute them in order, one at a time, and will wait for each to resolve.

```
const asyncA = async () => {
  return 'a'
}

const asyncB = async () => {
  return 'b'
}

const asyncC = async () => {
  return 'C'
}

const list = [asyncA, asyncB, asyncC]

for (const fn of list) {
  await fn() // call function to get returned Promise
}
```